# Javascript regex to match all characters to certain point inside content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having following kind of content in my code:

```
something();_c.log(<ANY CONTENT HERE>);somethingElse();
```

Now I'd like to have a regexp that returns:

```
something();somethingElse();
```

For some reason I can't get this (easily) done. How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use string replace with regex??

```
input = 'something();_c.log(<ANY CONTENT HERE>);somethingElse();'
input = input.replace(/(something\(\);).*?(somethingElse\(\);)/g, "$1$2");
```

Here it is capturing the two groups from your input and replacing everything excepts the two groups(`$1`, `$2`).

If the something and somethingElse are unknown, and the _c.log is fixed over there, then use this one:

```
input = input.replace(/(\w+\(\);)_c\.log.*?(\w+\(\);)/g, "$1$2");
```

Comment: Otherwise yes, but I don't know what "something();" and "somethingElse();" are. They're just functions and / or other code. I just need to get that _c.log(...); replaced with empty string.

Comment: @zvona please see my updated answer if you those names are unknown.

Comment: Thanks for help, that should do it. I also found that it's the minifier that does things that affect on the original format, therefore errors occur and the result isn't what I expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = 'something();_c.log(<ANY CONTENT HERE>);somethingElse();'
input = input.replace(/_c.log\(.*?\);/g, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2SY3w/